# [.\s]* is ignoring the dot?

Tags: php, regex, json

I'm trying to match an object inside some stringified json (because of some unfortunate server-specific PHP limitations).

My attempt: `/\{\s*"first":"first_entry_match"[.\s]*?\}/`

This should match any object inside the json whose first parameter is "first" with a corresponding value of "first_entry_match". After playing around, I've found that the `.` isn't working -- using `[\s\w":,]` goes very far, but I may end up dealing with some unicode and want to simply match *everything* until I get to the first `}` I see.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbangys1/) (I'm using PHP, but this illustrates the problem. Note that in my case, I do have newline characters in the json string)

Comment: Is this getting parsed in JavaScript? If so, are you aware that you can pass a "reviver" function to `JSON.parse`, and therefore easily target each `"first"` field? I can't imagine that you actually would need to use a regex on the entire JSON structure.

Comment: Do you really want to simply go to the first `}`? That won't work very well with something like `{"first":"first_entry_match","second":{"x":"y"}}`.

Comment: All values are strings, so that won't be an issue @TedHopp.

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm __not__ using javascript, at all. Just PHP without json_decode or json_encode functions

Comment: If all values are strings, then Avinash's answer is the way to go (provided it's guaranteed that none of the strings contain a `}` character).

Comment: @TedHopp Good point. I'll replace all `}` symbols with the html hex code `&#125;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match all the chars upto the first `}` symbol,   use a negated character class with the symbol `}`  , ie. `[^}]*`

```
/\{\s*"first":"first_entry_match"[^}]*\}/
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE0iR5/2)

Answer (score 4):

You have put the dot in the brackets. The dot represents every character when it is outside the bracket, inside, it simply represents the dot character.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
/\{\s*"first":"first_entry_match".*?\}/
```

`.*?` ensures there will be no `}` in the selection. (non-greedy)

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/dbangys1/1/

Comment: As I said, I have newline characters in my actual JSON.

Comment: @lucasem if you're running php then this regex should be changed to `(?s)\{\s*"first":"first_entry_match".*?\}` to match newline characters also.